# Android default browser keyboard causing resize

Tags: android, mobile, browser, web

I'm working on a website and I'm trying to make it work on mobile devices. Mostly it works fine but in the android default browser.

For instance I have text input for the date and I use the jquery calendar to help the user. So I don't really need the keyboard for that but it appears anyway since it's an input...

The problem is that the page and in this case the full page inframe is resized and when I hide the keyboard, the size is not restored. Rotating the device is enough to solve it but still I cannot tell that to the client.

Is it possible to prevent the keyboard from ever appearing or maybe trigger an event that would re draw the page ?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the jQuery blur() event you can prevent the date picker from triggering the keyboard. See this post [Disable setting of focus for jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911895/disable-setting-of-focus-for-jquery-ui-datepicker) for more information.

Comment: Hi tanks for your answer. From the link you gave I found using the readonly='true' attribute on the input works better as the text can black and not grey. FWI: i tried the blur but in some case the keyboard appeared for 1 sec then was hidden before it could completly open.

Answer (score 0):

From experience there is no easy way to force the keyboard to not come up when in a mobile browser and clicking on a text input(default functionality).

If the user will be always using the calender to pick the date then you can simply switch your text input to a div element.

give the div a click event and when clicked simply popup the jquery calender :) when they select the date just put it inside the div and that should take care of the problem

Another option is to simply give your textarea/input a disabled="disabled" attribute and that when the user clicks on it nothing will happen. you can then create your own onclick that will bring up the calender

```
$('#id').on('click', function()
{
   // bring up calender
});
```

and when the select the date you can insert it into the textinput via javascript..

If they cant actually click inside, the keyboard wont come up!