# Not enable the keyboard to select the textbox responsive

Tags: html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have fields with the jQuery UI Datepicker. I want mobile devices to have only a datepicker and no keyboard enabled.

How can I disable the keyboard on mobile devices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable setting of focus for jQuery UI datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911895/disable-setting-of-focus-for-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [Disable setting of focus for jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911895/disable-setting-of-focus-for-jquery-ui-datepicker)

> Set input to ReadOnly:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" id="datePicker" readonly>
> ```