# How to hide keyboard when focus in input in i pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, jquery-ui

[image: Correct image]
How to hide keyboard when focus in input in i pad

Answer (score 1):

If you need a pure javascript solution, use this line :

```
document.activeElement.blur();
```

This line removes the focus on the active element and hiding the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use readonly attribute or blur() right after the input is focused.

[Disable setting of focus for jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911895/disable-setting-of-focus-for-jquery-ui-datepicker)

Comment: $('#ArrivalDate,#DepartureDate').on('focus', function () { $(this).blur(); });i wrote this code but keyboard show for a second and disappear in IOS but in android it hide completely

Comment: Have you tried `event.preventDefault()` method? Ex: `$('#ArrivalDate,#DepartureDate').on('focus', function (e)  { e.preventDefault();  $(this).blur(); });`