# jQuery datetimepicker - how to prevent scroll / focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using jQuery datetimepicker on some datetime inputs. Whenever a user changes the date with the datetimepicker's popup calendar, the related input field is focused and hence the browser may automatically scroll up/down on mobile (which is awkward UI)

Is there a way to prevent this scrolling?

Thanks

Comment: I've just noticed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740253/disable-scrolling-when-changing-focus-form-elements-ipad-web-app but I don't think the solutions work perfectly to prevent scroll on focus; if someone knows e.g. how to prevent the focus happening in the first place that might be a better solution for me. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable setting of focus for jQuery UI datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911895/disable-setting-of-focus-for-jquery-ui-datepicker) - seems everyone makes it readonly, that way you also don't get the wrong date format entered